# Retrieve all files from all folders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, client-object-model, branding

I've a picture Library which contains to folders i've retrieved them by this code

```
getListItems('myList');
function getListItems(listName) {
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var lists = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
var collListItem;

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
var viewXML = "<View><ViewFields>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Modified' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Created' />"+
"</ViewFields></View>";

collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(oList);
clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        // We have the elements
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
         // It's easy to iterate and get the column values of an item
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var cItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            console.log('Id: ' + cItem.get_id() + ', Title: ' +cItem.get_item('Title')); 

        }

        // Run callback function if needed
        //if (onSuccess) onSuccess(collListItem);
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log('Error getting list items: ' + args.get_message());
        }
    );
 }
```

How Can i retrieve all files inside of each folder ?
im working on a project and i didnt work before with Jsom 
i'll be thankful for Help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using any where clause in the query you can also use `SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()` to get all items from the list.

> This method creates a Collaborative Application Markup Language (CAML)
>   string that can be used to recursively get all of the items in a list,
>   including the items in the subfolders.

Moreover, you can include the columns that you need in the `load` method like `clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title, Id)')`. This way only the fields that are needed will be returned hence improving the performance.
So, the code to query list will look like this:

```
var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

However, if you still want to use the view, then you need to set the `viewXml` of `CamlQuery` object like:

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
 var viewXML = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><ViewFields>" +
"<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='Modified' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='Created' />"+
"</ViewFields></View>";
 camlQuery.set_viewXml(viewXML)
```

Comment: Im still getting 
`Id: 1, Title: Gallery01
Id: 2, Title: Gallery02`

as output 
Gallery01 and 02 is the folders inside the list
i wanna know how to get the items inside them

Comment: I Got all Files inside of both of them
and thats Good What if i want to get Just the items thats in Gallery01 only ?

Comment: In that case you may want to set the `folderServerRelativeUrl` of the `camlQuery` object. See my blog post. This may be helpful: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/11/sharepoint-get-files-from-folder-using.html

Comment: Thanks very Much Nadeem 
your Blog was the best Help 
http://pastebin.com/kh1S7dB0
Heres the code that worked with me

Comment: I think You 'll be the best help for me for couple of days :D
my project almost 10 days to the deadline

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View `Scope="RecursiveAll"`

```
var viewXML = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><ViewFields>" +
"<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='Modified' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='Created' />"+
"</ViewFields></View>";
```